# Ruby - Converting Strings to CamelCase

Tags: ruby, string, camelcasing

I'm working on an exercise from Codewars. The exercise is to convert a string into camel case. For example, if I had

```
the-stealth-warrior
```

I need to convert it to

```
theStealthWarrior
```

Here is my code

```
def to_camel_case(str)
  words = str.split('-')
  a = words.first
  b = words[1..words.length - 1].map{|x|x.capitalize}
  new_array = []
  new_array << a << b
  return new_array.flatten.join('')
end
```

I just tested it out in IRB and it works, but in codewars, it won't let me pass. I get this error message.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand this, my method was definitely right.

Comment: This shouldn't fix your problem, but you an change `words[1..words.length - 1]` to `words[1...words.length]`

Comment: May fix the issue.Try to upload it without function

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about edge cases. In particular in this situation if the input was an empty string, then `words` would be `[]`, and so `words[1..words.length - 1]` would be `nil`.

Codewars is probably testing your code with a range of inputs, including the emplty string (and likely other odd cases).

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Ruby 2 for me, even if there's only one word in the input string:

```
def to_camel_case(str)
   str.split('-').map.with_index{|x,i| i > 0 ? x.capitalize : x}.join
end

to_camel_case("the-stealth-warrior")   # => "theStealthWarrior"
to_camel_case("warrior")   # => "warrior"
```

I know `.with_index` exists in 1.9.3, but I can't promise it will work with earlier versions of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to change the text is :

```
irb(main):022:0> 'the-stealth-warrior'.gsub('-', '_').camelize
 => "TheStealthWarrior"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 str.gsub("_","-").split('-').map.with_index{|x,i| i > 0 ? x.capitalize : x}.join
```

It accounts for words with underscores

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there's a test case with only one word?

In that case, you'd be trying to do a map on words[1..0], which is nil.

Add logic to handle that case and you should be fine.